# scriptcam - scriptcam screenshot size not work

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-10, scriptcam

I'm using [scriptcam](https://www.scriptcam.com/) and I have a problem with screenshot size **only in IE10**.
I init my webcam div with:

```
$("#webcam").scriptcam({        
        path: 'js/',
        width: 640,        
        height: 480,
        cornerRadius: 0            
    });
```

When I take a screenshot with

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + $.scriptcam.getFrameAsBase64();
image.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);     
};
```

my canvas has the photo resized at original value "320 pixels wide and 240 pixels high" and the other part is black.
How can I fix this problem??
Thanks for your help!
[UPDATE]
The problem is in the type of webcam: **changing the webcam whit a HD cam**, the size of the screenshot is ok. Is this a bug?